# Is there an equivalent to Dictionary or similar collection in Dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm looking for a way to store objects in a collection and identify them by UUID, then query the collection to get an object by UUID.  The closest example I can think of is the Dictionary collection in .NET.  Is there a recommended functionality in Dojo for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent in dojo, and even when the `dojo/store/Memory` module is not meant for this purpose, you can use it in some way as a collection, check this out:

```
require(["dojo/store/Memory"], function(Memory){
    var someData = [
        {id:1, name:"One"},
        {id:2, name:"Two"}
    ];

    store = new Memory({
        idProperty: "id", //define the id property
        data: someData
    });

    // Returns the object with an id of 1
    store.get(1);

    // Returns query results from the array that match the given query
    store.query({name:"One"});

    // Pass a function to do more complex querying
    store.query(function(object){
        return object.id > 1;
    });

    // Returns query results and sort by id
    store.query({name:"One"}, {sort: [{attribute: "id"}]});

    // store the object with the given identity
    store.put({id:3, name:"Three"}); 

    // delete the object
    store.remove(3); 
});
```

dojo has other types of `store` that may suit more to your case than the `dojo/store/Memory`. Here are some links to docs:

[dojo/store/Memory](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/Memory.html)
[dojo/store/JsonRest](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/JsonRest.html)
[dojo/store/DataStore](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/DataStore.html)
[dojo/store/Cache](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/Cache.html)

Exist others, but this are the must commons

Answer (score 0):

There is not such objects has Collection in JavaScript. But you could create your own Objects like below

```
var coll = { uid : "value" };
coll['uid2'] = "value2;
```

This can be accessed using

```
var a = coll['uid'];
```

This is the beauty of JavaScript.